# upload image then check the max criteria then create thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

greeting for the day

my task is:

step1:upload an image.

step2:check the criteria of uploading image with our max dimension(xyx or eg:500X500)

step3:if criteria matches then create a thumbnail of 145X190 dimension

done by me: i am able to upload an image and also done criteria validation.

now i want create thumbnail of that image which is uploading by user.(145X190 dimension 
)

my coading is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Tooltip - Default functionality</title>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () { 
function readImage(file) {

    var reader = new FileReader();
    var image = new Image();
    var maxh = 600;
    var maxw = 600;
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = function (_file) {
        image.src = _file.target.result; // url.createObjectURL(file);
        image.onload = function () {
            var w = this.width,
                h = this.height,
                t = file.type, // ext only: // file.type.split('/')[1],
                n = file.name,
                s = ~~ (file.size / 1024) + 'KB';
            if (w > maxw && h > maxh) {
                alert("Height and width is bigger then over max criteria pls select image max height and width                                            =2024X2024");
                alert(width);
                alert(height);
            } else {


                $('#uploadPreview').html('<img src="' + this.src + '"> ' + w + 'x' + h + ' ' + s + ' ' + t + ' ' + n + '<br>');
            }

        };
        image.onerror = function () {
            alert('Invalid file type: ' + file.type);
        };
    };

}

$("#choose").change(function (e) {
    if (this.disabled) return alert('File upload not supported!');
    var F = this.files;
    if (F && F[0]) for (var i = 0; i < F.length; i++) readImage(F[i]);
});

});
</script>



<style>



</style>
</head>
<body >
<input type="file" id="choose" multiple="multiple"  onchange="readImage(this);" />
<br>
<div id="uploadPreview" ></div>

</body>
</html>
```

problem:Create thumbnail after uploading an image.

I also create the thumbnail coding but not able to combine both code.

my code is:

```
<html>
<head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/imgareaselect-default.css" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.imgareaselect.pack.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
            var thumbWidth = 145, thumbHeight = 190;

            function preview(img, selection) {
            var scaleX = thumbWidth / (selection.width || 1);
            var scaleY = thumbHeight / (selection.height || 1);

            $('#ferret + div > img').css({
                width: Math.round(scaleX * $("#ferret").width()) + 'px',
                height: Math.round(scaleY * $("#ferret").height()) + 'px',
                marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(scaleX * selection.x1) + 'px',
                marginTop: '-' + Math.round(scaleY * selection.y1) + 'px'
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('<div><img src="http://jotform.org/demo/jquery-image-area-select-plugin/images/sweet-dogs.jpg" style="position: relative;" /><div>')
                .css({
                    float: 'right',
                    position: 'relative',
                    overflow: 'hidden',
                    width: thumbWidth + 'px',
                    height: thumbHeight + 'px'
                })
                .insertAfter($('#ferret'));

            $('#ferret').imgAreaSelect({aspectRatio: thumbWidth+':'+thumbHeight, onSelectChange: preview ,minWidth: 100,minHeight: 100,maxWidth: 180,maxHeight: 180});
        });
</script>

</head>
<body>

   <img src="http://jotform.org/demo/jquery-image-area-select-plugin/images/sweet-dogs.jpg" id="ferret" ><br>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope you understand my question...

Comment: Do you want to create the thumbnail on the client side only or you have the option of doing the image processing on the server side.?

Comment: on same page user side

Answer (score 0):

For the thumbnail , i would advice that you create a div and set its background image instead of using  `<img>` tag as it will cause issues with the scaling and aspect ratio.

You can use the following code to achieve that

```
 $('<div> <div>')
               .css({
                   'width': thumbWidth + 'px',
                   'height': thumbHeight + 'px',
                   'background': "url('http://jotform.org/demo/jquery-image-area-select-plugin/images/sweet-dogs.jpg')",
                   'background-size': '100% 100%',
                   'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
                   'float': 'right',
                   'background-origin': 'content-box'

           })
               .insertAfter($('#ferret'));
```

You might want to add the vendor prefix like `-moz-`, `-webkit-` to the css properties above  for supporting old browsers.

You can access the file then pass it to the   `readImage()` function , if it returns `false` ( you can modify the function to do that) then do not proceed. otherwise process the image and generate a thumbnail for it using the above code

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xKTU2/1/